# Fourier Transform of $\exp(-t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

$$f(t)= \begin{cases}
e^{-t} & 0<t<1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

How can I solve this function's Fourier transform?

I am stuck at here:

> [*Daniel R*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83553/daniel-r) - OP
>   \begin{align}
> F(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\exp(-2\pi itk)\;\mathrm dt \\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\exp(-t)\exp(-2\pi itk)\;\mathrm dt \\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\exp(-2\pi itk-t)\;\mathrm dt \\
> &=\int_{0}^{1}\exp((-2\pi ik-1)t)\;\mathrm dt \\
> \end{align}

Comment: Hint: by definition. By the way, are $x$ and $t$ related?

Comment: I've just realised that i wrote the equation **wrongly**.Sorry about that.

Comment: I am new to TeX commands. So I could not write where I am stuck at. Therefore I could not identified my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the defintion of Fourier transform gives you

$$\begin{align}
F(k)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\exp(-2\pi itk)\;\mathrm dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\exp(-t)\exp(-2\pi itk)\;\mathrm dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\exp(-2\pi itk-t)\;\mathrm dt \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\exp((-2\pi ik-1)t)\;\mathrm dt \\
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Using the definiontion of f, we can plug it in the usual Fourier Transform formula $$\hat{f(\xi)}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(t)e^{-2\pi i\xi t}dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}{e^{-t(1+2\pi i \xi)}dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-e}{1+2\pi i \xi}$$

Comment: Isn't $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ a part of Inverse Fourier Transform?